# Django Tag object

Tags: django-tagging

Django Tag object has a default function add_tag(), it seems it only allow one word for the tag name, is there anyway to save a tag contains more than one words?

Comment: Please identify the package you are referring to with more particularity.

Comment: Yes, I am using django-tagging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using django-tagging, you can add tags with spaces by either putting quotes around the tag or using commas to separate the tags. It makes sense in the context of adding multiple tags, but I think it works the same for individual tags too.

Note: The following code is untested

```
Tag.objects.add_tag(obj, '"banana split"')
Tag.objects.add_tag(obj, 'banana split,')
```